# Two columns with different background in container

Tags: html, css, bulma

I have an issue with a specific layout with bulma container. I want to show a layout with two columns inside a container, left background part must be gray and right white. I need to wrap columns inside container for size and breakpoints.

```css
.container{
  min-height: 100vh
}

.left{
  background-color: lightgray;  
  min-height: 100vh
}

.right{
  background-color: white; 
  min-height: 100vh
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css">
<nav class="navbar has-background-grey-dark">
  <div class="container">
<div class="navbar-brand">
  <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
    <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo-white.png" width="112" height="28">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-menu">
  <div class="navbar-start">
    <a class="navbar-item">
      Home
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-end">
    <div class="navbar-item">
      <div class="buttons">
        <a class="button is-primary">
          <strong>Sign up</strong>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
<div class="column is-9 left">
  Left
</div>
<div class="column">
  Right
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see I work here: https://codepen.io/hans-felix/pen/GRqKeYe

**Current result:**

[image: Current result]

**Expected result:**

[image: Expected result]

I use containers to align items as you can see.
How Can I hanlde this design?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what is breaking ? The fact that it is breaking under 769px is not fiting you ?

Comment: maybe you also need to call vegeta container to solve problem

Comment: On desktop, all outside container is white, I need to get it as expected result

Comment: I add a current result image @MaxiGui

Comment: Vegeta container @Rehan

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
    .navbar {
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
}

.row {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
 
 .column1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  background-color:lightgrey;
  padding-left:80px;
}

 .column2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  padding-right:80px;
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css">
<nav class="navbar has-background-grey-dark"> 
<div class="navbar-brand">
  <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
    <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo-white.png" width="112" height="28">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-menu">
  <div class="navbar-start">
    <a class="navbar-item">
      Home
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-end">
    <div class="navbar-item">
      <div class="buttons">
        <a class="button is-primary">
          <strong>Sign up</strong>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>

<body>
 <div class="row">
<div class="column1">
  Left
</div>
<div class="column2">
  Right
</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

When you inspect your result, you can look and see that the margin is what is making the white space off to the left side. If you set the margin to zero, it should pull it over. The nav bar should be in its own container that isn't affected by any other containers on the page.

Comment: thanks, but I want to mantain the margins inside container because I have other elements and I need them to be aligned.

Comment: so you just want the grey to extend to the left further?

Comment: I update mi question, I added a header. I want to mantain alignment in bulma logo and left text.

Comment: @HansFelixRamos I updated my code above to reflect the changes

Answer (score 1):

Flex should help with this.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex
Maybe you don't even need the "container" DIV.

```css
.columns {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  background-color: lightgray;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.right {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex: unset;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Your header stuff here ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... .. .... .. .. . .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  </div>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-9 left">
      Left
    </div>
    <div class="column right">
      Right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I think maybe dont need a container. But I use to align items inside it. I update mi question and I added a header

Comment: So, the Right column needs to be of a certain width, and the left column needs to take the remainder of the space?

Comment: Yes, in this case,container has an exactyl witdh depends on breakpoints

Comment: Check updated response then. I think this should do.

Comment: Ok, I think flex hlep to hanlde columns, but i need to left text and bulma logo be aligned, see my expected result image.

Comment: Your headers need to go in a sibling container like the one I just added to my response.